# Pentaho Dashboard Error processing component

Tags: pentaho, dashboard

I'm new in Pentaho, I'm using sql over sqlJndi, mysql query is using some external parameter.
I followed the instructions on this link http://pentaho-bi-suite.blogspot.com/2013/08/date-input-controlscomponets-in-pentaho.html
but, when I use a Date Parameter I get the error 'Error processing component'
any help please?

PS : I'm calling the the external parameter on my query like this

> AND (wo.start_date <= ${date_param})

my parameter are defined like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlAQY.jpg)

Comment: Without more informations, it will be hard to understand what's going wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You done a mistake in **Date Parameter**. In **Date Parameter** of **property** section, **Property date value** make it as blank (remove **yesterday**).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've tried Property date value, with and without value, but I have the same result

Comment: With out parameter the SQL is running fine in dashboard?